# React Navigation navigation options access props

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

How can the conditional be implemented in React navigation navigation options?

```
 static navigationOptions = {
   headerTitle: this.props.moneyContext === 'Send' ? 'Send money' : 'Receive money',
 };
```

moneyContext depends on what screen is opened and gets data from store.

Thanks!

Comment: this seems right, what's problem or error here ?

Answer (score 1):

You can give it a try to use setParams:

```
navigation.setParams({ param: value })
```

See the [documentation on headers](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/headers.html#updating-navigationoptions-with-setparams) for more detail.